# Are these used for interop or for COM coding?

Tags: c#, winapi, c#-4.0, com, com-interop

I have the below code, but I have no clue what it means or how it works.

I only know that it calls functions and these all are just declarations, so where can I find definitions for this code?

```
   [ComImport, Guid("341A80AC-5FC6-4B$6-8380-4D70279300CZ"), TypeLibType((short) 2), ClassInterface((short) 0)]
    public class WjbJobClass : abc, xyz
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x20)]
        public virtual extern int somefunction();
    }
```

Can i use the same to call function from other application?

Comment: Looks like wrapper created manually. More infos at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8fbsf00.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is a declaration that was auto-generated by the Tlbimp.exe tool.  From the type library for a COM component.  The implementation of the method is buried inside some native DLL, one that you almost certainly don't have source code for.  If that component is properly registered then you can find it back by looking in the registry with Regedit.exe.

Navigate to HKCR\Classes\CLSID and look for the {guid} you see used in the declaration.  The InProcServer32 key gives the path to the DLL.  You can use the OleView.exe tool to look at the type library inside the DLL.  Which will tell you pretty much what you already know from the Tlbimp generated declaration.  Contact the owner of the COM component if you need support to troubleshoot a problem.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. Can i use the same to call function from other application?

Comment: I cannot answer that, it is too imprecise.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to view the definitions of the wrapped COM object is run "OleView.exe". It is part of the Windows SDK and will show you all the COM classes, interfaces and type libraries in a Windows system. You might have to use also RegEdit to find the class id associated with the GUID. When you do this all you will be able to see is the C definitions of the interface to the COM library, not the implementation. If you need to figure out how something is implemented you could a dissasembler, like IDA.